# Visual Studio checked iterator not throwing exceptions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, iterator

I have this code:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define _SECURE_SCL 1
#define _SECURE_SCL_THROWS 1
#else
#define _SECURE_SCL 0
#define _SECURE_SCL_THROWS 0
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;




int main()
{
    vector <int> v1;
    v1.push_back(33);

    vector <int>::iterator it1 = v1.begin();

    try 
    {
        it1++;

        it1++;
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        cout << "vector is empty!!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A pretty simple one: I try to go past-the-boundary and I want the exception to be caught. However the program simply crashes with a "Debug Assertion Failed!" on the second increment, why is that?

The example was taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965(v=vs.100).aspx and I just added the macros to set the checked iterators on. I'm in debug mode, /EHsc is on and so is /MDd

Comment: I think you need to define those macros before you include the header for vector.

Comment: @NathanMonteleone: He shouldn't be defining those macros at all.  According to the article he linked, he should be compiling with `/D_DEBUG /EHsc /MDd`

Comment: Isn't that the same if I define those macros in the source code?

Comment: by the way /EHsc is active and /MDd too

Comment: @MooingDuck: According to the linked article, the default for `_SECURE_SCL_THROWS` is zero even in debug mode.  He DOES need to define them himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of Visual C++'s library (bundled in Visual Studio 2010) doesn't support throwing exceptions from checked iterators.  See http://wishmesh.com/2010/04/it-seems-that-_secure_scl_throws-is-deprecated-in-visual-studio-c-2010/

Comment: That solves the matter, but the documentation could have been clearer on this.. thank you

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: Looks like they did fix the documentation for the next version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You left the most important part out of your question -- the `#include` lines.

You need to put those macros ABOVE the `#include` lines.  If you're using precompiled headers, you need to put them in the precompiled header.

Because the code in your question is not complete, I can't tell if you've done this right.  I suspect you haven't, so I'm offering this as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I tried moving it above them but nothing changed.. except that the compiler is telling me "warning CRT1008: _SECURE_SCL_THROWS is deprecated"

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: If you look at the `#warning` line emitting that message, is there a comment nearby suggesting some other approach?

Comment: Unfortunately.. no :(

1>  VSProject.cpp
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\yvals.h(252): warning CRT1008: _SECURE_SCL_THROWS is deprecated
1>  array.cpp
1>  Generating Code...

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: I meant look in yvals.h near line 252.  It should be as easy as double-clicking the warning.  But see my new answer.

Comment: Thank you Ben, but seems that the exception throwing is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

> A checked iterator refers to an iterator that will throw an exception
>   or call invalid_parameter if you attempt to move past the boundaries
>   of the container.

Your example code isn't moving an iterator, so I don't think it makes sense that anything would be thrown.

Comment: thanks but that didn't solve my problem, I changed the code of the question though